# RSpec skip one of many validations in creating an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to write RSpec test for one of my Models. I want my test to test validations as well, but I will like to skip a specific validation, only in the test.

I understand that to skip validations, I can do pass in a `(:validate => false)` option to my `create` or `save` action, but my understanding is that this will skip all the validations for the Model.

What I want is to skip only a specific validation.

The validations in my model is as follow:

```
  validates :user_id, :name, :description, :address, :image, :spot_type, :internet_options, presence: true
  validate :image_size_validation
```

I want all validations to take effect, but only skip validation for `presence of image`. Reason is that I don't want to be populating the `s3` space where I'm hosting images, each time I run the test.

Comment: well, you;d rather changer your storage settings in test env

Comment: @apneadiving, thank you for your suggestion, but could you expatiate on this? I'm not sure I understand what you are saying.

Comment: your uploader settings depend on the environment, for test you could set it to local storage

Comment: ha... ok, let me check that out. thank you, I'll get back to you soon enough.

Comment: @apneadiving this is what I came up with:

`Rails.env == "test" || "development" ?  storage :file : storage :fog`

hope this is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specifically test **validations**, you may just build objects without saving them and then test calling `#valid?` method.
Something like (assuming FactoryGirl for creation)

```
expect(build(:something, { field: value })).to be_valid
```

If you want to save objects with validations running, but avoid using S3, as suggested by @apneadiving in the comment, you may change storage setting for test environment. You can do that by modifying the carrierwave initializer like

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.test?
    config.storage = :file
  end
end
```